# Is it possible to pass arrays to events?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I've seen no documentation on whether this is possible or not, and when I tried the following code, I get a revert error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Hello {

    event TestEvent(uint256[] array);

    function hello() public {
        uint256[] memory output;
        for (uint i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            output[i] = i;
        }
        TestEvent(output);
    }

}
```

The compiler raises no warnings about this code, so I'm unsure if it's some other issue or because I'm trying to pass an array to an event.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can pass an array as an event parameter. Your current code is broken because you're accessing `output` with an index that's out of bounds.

You might be tempted to fix this with `output.push(i)`, but per https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays:

> Creating arrays with variable length in memory can be done using the
>   `new` keyword. As opposed to storage arrays, it is **not** possible to
>   resize memory arrays by assigning to the `.length` member.

You instead need to allocate the array with the right size to start with. This code works:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Hello {

    event TestEvent(uint256[] array);

    function hello() public {
        uint256[] memory output = new uint256[](5);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            output[i] = i;
        }
        TestEvent(output);
    }
}
```